# Get timezones with utc offset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

is there a module or public API that given the UTC offset returns a list of all timezones in that offset ?

For example given UTC+2 it returns the following list:
Africa/Blantyre Africa/Bujumbura
Africa/Cairo    Africa/Gaborone
Africa/Harare   Africa/Johannesburg
Africa/Juba Africa/Khartoum
Africa/Kigali   Africa/Lubumbashi
Africa/Lusaka   Africa/Maputo
Africa/Maseru   Africa/Mbabane
Africa/Tripoli  Africa/Windhoek
Asia/Amman  Asia/Beirut
Asia/Damascus   Asia/Famagusta
Asia/Gaza   Asia/Hebron
Asia/Jerusalem  Asia/Nicosia
Europe/Athens   Europe/Bucharest
Europe/Chisinau Europe/Helsinki
Europe/Kaliningrad  Europe/Kiev
Europe/Mariehamn    Europe/Riga
Europe/Sofia    Europe/Tallinn
Europe/Uzhgorod Europe/Vilnius
Europe/Zaporozhye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of daylight savings, the result depends on the current time.

```
>>> for zone in sorted(zoneinfo.available_timezones()):
...     tz = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(zone)
...     if datetime.datetime.now(tz).utcoffset() == datetime.timedelta(hours=2):
...         print(tz)
Africa/Blantyre
Africa/Bujumbura
Africa/Cairo
Africa/Gaborone
Africa/Harare
Africa/Johannesburg
Africa/Juba
Africa/Khartoum
Africa/Kigali
Africa/Lubumbashi
Africa/Lusaka
Africa/Maputo
Africa/Maseru
Africa/Mbabane
Africa/Tripoli
Africa/Windhoek
Asia/Amman
Asia/Beirut
Asia/Damascus
Asia/Famagusta
Asia/Gaza
Asia/Hebron
Asia/Jerusalem
Asia/Nicosia
Asia/Tel_Aviv
EET
Egypt
Etc/GMT-2
Europe/Athens
Europe/Bucharest
Europe/Chisinau
Europe/Helsinki
Europe/Kaliningrad
Europe/Kiev
Europe/Mariehamn
Europe/Nicosia
Europe/Riga
Europe/Sofia
Europe/Tallinn
Europe/Tiraspol
Europe/Uzhgorod
Europe/Vilnius
Europe/Zaporozhye
Israel
Libya
```

Python 3.9+ required for stdlib [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module.